# How to add swipe action to wordpress pages

Tags: navigation, user-interface

I have a news website. I have the main front-page and also a couple of "sub" front pages (sport, social). The other sections works through category.php.

I like to add a touch gesture functionality, [like this one http://jedrzejchalubek.com/glide/](http://jedrzejchalubek.com/glide/), but how can I do it?

I mean, how can I load different pages, that are always different? What I see is that these kind of script just positions differently content already loaded. Any ideas?